# Return statement confusing me. Unsure how to use it

Tags: java

Hey guys I'm a little more new to programming. I did a little in High School and I'm trying to get back into it. I'm using Codecademy right now to learn Java again. Since I'll be trying to stay active I figured an account here would be wise.

I'm learning about the Return statement right now and I'm getting it to work just fine... I could move on in ignorance pretending like I know whats going on but I don't. Everywhere I've used a Return statement here confuses me because it feels as if I can throw any instance/variable of the right data type into the return statement and the code will run unaffected.

For example I changed the return statement under the `energyReport` method from `return batteryLevel` to `return chargePak` although there are no parameters here and the instance I'm using in this method is `batteryLevel`. Please criticize my code I'm always willing to learn and I know I am new. Tell me what I am doing wrong! Help me learn and thank you so much!

**My Code:**

```
public class Droid {
String name;
int batteryLevel;
int chargePak;

  //constructor
  public Droid(String droidName){
    name = droidName;
    batteryLevel = 100;
    chargePak = 400;
  }

  //toString method
  public String toString() {
    return "Meet " + name + " our newest droid!";
  }

  //Perform Task method
  public void performTask(String task) {
    System.out.println(name + " is performing " + task + "!");
    batteryLevel = batteryLevel - 10;
  }

  //Energy Report
  public int energyReport() {
    System.out.println("You have " + batteryLevel + "% remaining.");
   return chargePak;
  }

    //Energy Report for chargepak
  public int pakReport() {
    System.out.println("You have " + chargePak + "% remaining in your Charge Pak.");
   return chargePak;
  }

  //Energy Transfer
  public void chargeDroid(int charge) {
    chargePak = chargePak - charge;
    batteryLevel = charge + batteryLevel;
    System.out.println("Charging...\n" + "You now have " + batteryLevel + "% battery!");
  }

  //Main Method
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Droid codey = new Droid("Codey");
    System.out.println(codey);
    codey.energyReport();
    codey.performTask("Jump");
    codey.energyReport();
    codey.performTask("Punch");
    codey.performTask("Punch");
    codey.performTask("Kick");
    codey.performTask("Dab");
    codey.energyReport();
    codey.chargeDroid(20);
    codey.chargeDroid(20);
    codey.pakReport();
  }
}
```

Comment: Seeing as you do not use the value that is returned from any method, they should all be declared as `void`, same as you did for `public void chargeDroid`

Comment: How could this be changed in a way for me to see how I should actually be using return?

Comment: `int foo = codey.energyReport();`  and then do something with `foo`

Comment: Since you mentioned we should criticize: Your indention is not always consistent, you should fix that. It will also make reading the code easier for yourself.

Comment: See what I mean: https://codebeautify.org/javaviewer/cb204d24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I wanted to say kudos for this attitude. You are actually trying to understand what you are learning fully, and don't leave things be that feel weird to you. This is the way to go.

Now to the answer:

`return` returns a value from a function to its caller. For example:

```java
public static int giveMeTheAnswer () {
  return 42;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
  int answer = giveMeTheAnswer();
  System.out.println("The answer is " + answer); // Prints "The answer is 42"
}
```

Java lets you also ignore the return value, in this case it's just thrown away:

```java
public static int giveMeTheAnswer () {
  return 42;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
  giveMeTheAnswer(); // This call is now useless
  System.out.println("The answer was lost...");
}
```

In your case, your functions actually have *side-effects*, namely printing stuff to the console themselves. This way, they don't actually have to return anything, as you aren't using the return value in the first place, instead you are calling the functions for their side-effects only.

If you don't need a return value, you can declare the functions as returning `void`, then you can simply use `return;` to return (without value), or omit the `return` entirely (because at the end of the function it returns automatically):

```java
public static void printMeTheAnswer () {
  System.out.println("The answer is 42");
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
  printMeTheAnswer();
}
```